# Understand KLEE test data for array or pointer

Tags: unit-testing, klee

I am using KLEE to generate test data for function. But the test data generated by KLEE makes me in some troubles.

Input:

```
void arrange(int a[]) {
    ...
}
```

Here is a test data in KLEE:

```
...
object    0: name: 'a'
object    0: size: 40
object    0: data:
'\xa0\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

In this test case, I have understood that the size of variable a is 40 bytes. It means that each block of four continuous numbers (e.g., the first block `\xa0\xff\xff\xff` represents an integer). However, what is the demical value of `\xa0\xff\xff\xff`?

Answer (score 0):

For KLEE, it's just a memory block.

> klee_make_symbolic() function, which takes three arguments: the address of the variable (memory location) that we want to treat as symbolic, its size, and a name (which can be anything).

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer it to integer by writing:

```
ktest-tool --write-ints t000001.ktest
```

Comment: For integer variable, I can see its real value. However, it is not in human readable format if the variable belongs to array.